# looking for a creative way to store all my tubing

Tags: storage, tubing

Every time I brew I think to myself, "damn there has to be a better way to store all this tubing"! Currently I have a drawer (twice the size of a file cabinet) where I throw my racking canes, tubing, and rando crap but it sure is unorganized. I do store my stock, yet to be used tubing coiled vertically in beer boxes which works great for that purpose (not having to access it often). figured I would see if anyone out there has a good ideas!

Comment: Could you wind it around an old cardboard tube (such as from paper towels or toilet paper)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I mounted an empty, plastic speaker wire spool to the wall in my brewing closet (room under the stairs where I kept all my brewing equipment) to hang all the tubing on.  I made sure to mount it high enough on the wall that I didn't have to coil the tubing around the spool.  This allowed the tubing to dry well and kept off the ground and out of my way.  The spool was deep enough that I was able to lay all the sections of tubing side by side so they weren't stacked on top of each other.

Answer (score 3):

I mounted a garden hose tidy to the wall - it's semicircular and not too deep. I hang all the tubes from that. It allows them to drip dry and gives easy access.

(It's late here, I'll post a picture during daylight.)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an open wallspace?  Perhaps you could hang the tubing in a coil (and perhaps your canes, brushes, etc as well), as one might with tools in a garage?